# Is cgroup a type of namespace?

Tags: cgroups, namespace, network-namespaces

Is cgroup a type of namespace?

I am asking this because I have seen blogs talking as if cgroup and namespaces are different. However, in different linux commands , cgroup is considered as a type of namespace. For example,

```
% unshare --help | grep cgroup
 -C, --cgroup[=<file>]     unshare cgroup namespace
% lsns --help | grep cgroup
 -t, --type <name>      namespace type (mnt, net, ipc, user, pid, uts, cgroup)
```

What is actually going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [a number of different namespace types](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html), and Cgroup is one of them:

- Cgroup
- IPC
- Network
- Mount
- PID
- Time
- User
- UTS (hostname and NIS domain name)

But cgroups and [cgroup namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroup_namespaces.7.html) are manipulated differently; cgroup namespaces virtualise cgroup hierarchies. Most of the time you’d only use cgroups directly, without caring about cgroup namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I find Stephen Kitt's answer to be accurate.  However, if you're still having trouble understanding, perhaps the following way of looking at the question might help.

Pick one of the namespaces with a feature that you understand well.  Maybe network (net).  And ask this question: "Are network and network namespace the same thing?".  No they are not the same thing, but there is a relation between the two.  In Linux, network can mean things like interfaces, ip addresses, routing tables, filtering rules (e.g. iptables/nft).  You can then have a number of network namespaces on your system, where inside each of these network namespaces, you have your own set of interfaces, ip addresses, routing tables, filtering rules.  The namespace creates a bit of a virtual environment for a particular Linux feature (network in my example).

The same would be for cgroup.  In Linux cgroup can mean a way to limit and keep track of resources (e.g. CPUs and memory).  You can then have a number of cgroup namespaces on your system, where inside each of these group namespaces, you have your own set of limits and tracking of resources.